# How do you pad lists in a dataframe if the lists contain 'str' values?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

I'm trying to get my dataframe to go from this:

```
my_list            list_length

[nan,1,2,3]        4
[1,2,nan,3,4,5]    6
[1,nan]            2
```

To this:

```
    my_list            list_length

[nan,1,2,3,pad,pad,pad]        6
[1,2,nan,3,4,5]                6
[1,nan,pad,pad,pad,pad]        6
```

Basically, I need to pad the lists in the dataframe so that they are all as long as the longest list.

I've tried this:

```
def pad(some_list, target_len):
    aux = ['pad']*(target_len - len(some_list))
    some_list.extend(aux)
    return some_list

for i in df["audio_data"]:
    pad(i,6)
```

But I realized my issue is that not all of the values are numeric. Now I'm trying to figure out how to go about this. My first thought is to change all the nan values to 0. So I tried this code:

```
for row in df["audio_data"]:
for i in row: 
    if i =='nan':
        i==0
```

But this didn't change any of the nan values to 0. So if that's the best way to move forward, how do I do that? I'm also worried that if I change all the nan values to 0, I'll need to pad with a string. In my actual dataframe, there are so many different numbers, I couldn't choose a number to represent padding. Will I run into a similar issue if I try to pad the list using a string in a list of only integers?

I just need some way to indicate where the null values are and then pad the strings so that they are all the same length. What exactly I use to indicate nan values and padding doesn't really matter.

Comment: Why does it matter if not all of the values are numeric? You're padding with a string. `nan` is a numpy datatype

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters. It keeps giving me this error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'

While I didn't think nan was a string, I don't know what else the error could be referring to. There are no string values in any of the lists.